# Leaflet Maps Marker Popup Open on Hashtag from URL

Tags: leaflet

I am passing a latlng from a link on another page to my map. My map has the markers based on this latlng. So what I am passing is exactly what the map markers are using to show on the map.

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
var hashless = hash.replace("#", "");
var ll = hashless.split(",", 2);
map.setView(new L.LatLng(ll[0], ll[1]), 14);
```

This is working great, but I am struggling at getting the marker to show it's infowindow. I would like only the link clicked on to be the marker that is showing it's popup. I am able to zoom right to the marker, but not able to get the popup to work in a reasonable way.

I have tried a few things, but map.getBounds() seems to be the one I should be working with, *unless you can ID a marker based on Lat/Lng.* Can you?

I am using bounds in the map.on function.... but none of the events seems to really work well. Originally thought LOAD would do it, but no results... viewreset, mousemove, etc... all show the popup in this simple function, but it is not really any good as it flickers etc... when moving things around:

```
map.on('viewreset', function () {
                // Construct an empty list to fill with onscreen markers.
                console.log("YA");
                var inBounds = [], bounds = map.getBounds();
                datalayer.eachLayer(function (marker) {
                    if (bounds.contains(marker.getLatLng())) {
                        inBounds.push(marker.options.title);
                        marker.openPopup();
                    }
                });
            });
```

How can I set the marker.openPopup() from my link to the current marker at that lat/lng passed to it?

Comment: you could probably/theoretically loop(`.eachLayer`) through the featureGroup containing all the markers, and identify the marker with the matching coordinates by inspecting the results of  `.getLatLng()`.